# Cuda - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 OS X

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cuda

Here is my make file output:

```
nvcc -c -arch=sm_35    src/kmeans_cuda.cu
nvcc -c -arch=sm_35    src/sequence.c
nvcc -c -arch=sm_35    src/io.c
nvcc -c -arch=sm_35    src/main.c 
nvcc -g  -o   cuda-means  kmeans_cuda.o sequence.o io.o main.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_kmeans", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
     (maybe you meant: cudaError (anonymous namespace)::cudaLaunch<char>(char*))
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

On my main function i call `kmeans();`, kmeans, is a  C function defined in kmeans_cuda.cu

```
void kmeans() {
long i,h,j,k; //counters
long delta; //Number of objects has diverged in current iteration
long nearest; //Nearest centroid
unsigned int distance,min_distance; //distance calculated by relation point-cluster

int *count,*recv_count;
int *send_label;
double begin,end,trans_init,trans_end;
// should call kernel, but is not calling yet, because it's not implemented  ...
```

I already try to added `__host__` on kmeans() declaration, but dind't fixed the problem.
I have now idea why i'm getting this error, because i'm linking the object with the function.

Comment: Try to add option `-m64` to nvcc. And/or change .c to .cpp

Comment: @Eric: This is a C++ symbol mangling problem, not architecture mismatch.

Comment: @talonmies I am not sure so I give two guesses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nvcc treats `.cu` files as C++ and you have your host code in `.c` files (i.e. in C, not C++).

The easiest solution is to simply rename your `.c` files to `.cpp` and treat your app as a C++ app instead of C. You could also declare `kmeans()` as `extern "C" {...}` to force the compiler to use a C binding instead of C++ binding for the function, but then you'd have to do that for every future function which is probably unnecessarily inelegant.

Comment: Extern "C" worked, i didn't know that nvcc compile .c class as c++.

Comment: nvcc is not compiling C as C++ (and there's no such thing as a C class). By convention, .cpp files are C++ and .c files are C. .cu files are C++ files that can contain device code. Note also that for host code nvcc just invokes the host compiler anyway. Glad you got it sorted, as I said though I'd probably go the C++ route rather than C, but that's your call!

Comment: Ops, i should have say .c files. What i'm saying is my file has a .c extension, i thought nvcc will invoke gcc to compile host code but seems it invoke g++.